# Use CP2102 as self-powered or bus-powered

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, lipo, cp2102

I'm drawing a LiPo 3.7V charger circuit. This circuit contains a power path to continue delivering power to the circuit, or by battery or usb. In the final of the circuit I've an LDO to 3v3.

Now, I want to use CP2102 as an RS232 converter and my question is: Should I supply CP2102 with power from the BUS pin?

[image]
Or should I feed it with the 3v3 that come from the LDO?

[image]
The second options seems to be better to me, becouse:

1. I don't need the 3v3 from voltage regulator (REG0)
2. Using Bus as supply it could affect the behaviour of my power path?!

I've a few more questions about it.

1. Whenever I disconnect VBus the CP2102 automatically enters on standby mode?
2. Should I use any pull-up resistor on D+ and D-? Datasheet doesn't make any reference to that.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

> Should I supply CP2102 with power from the BUS pin?

You MUST always connect VBUS to the +5V feed in some way (either directly or through a divider). The IC will not operate otherwise, it uses this signal as an indication that USB is connected.

> Or should I feed it with the 3v3 that come from the LDO?

Per the [datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/CP2102-9.pdf),

> Alternatively, if 3 V power is supplied to the VDD pin, the CP2102/9 can function as a USB self-powered device withthe voltage regulator disabled. For this configuration, it is recommended that the REGIN input be tied to the 3 V net to  disable  the  voltage  regulator.  In  addition,  if  VDD or REGIN  may  be  unpowered  while  VBUS  is  5 V,  a  resistor divider  (or  functionally-equivalent  circuit)  shown  in  Note  1  of  Figure 8  and  Figure 10  is  required  to  meet  theabsolute maximum voltage on VBUS specification in Table 2.

No matter what, all of the configurations show at least some connection to VBUS - either directly or through a resisor-divider.

> Whenever I disconnect VBus the CP2102 automatically enters on standby mode?

I'm not sure about that, but most likely the USB transceiver would go idle since the chip would recognize that the USB connection is not present.

> Should I use any pull-up resistor on D+ and D-? Datasheet doesn't make any reference to that.

This is fundamental USB knowledge, so the datasheet author most likely skipped this in the datasheet. Pullups - no. Depending on your PCB layout, it sometimes does not hurt to put zero-ohm resistors in series with D+ and D- in case you need to tweak the impedances slightly (i.e. if you get data errors with long cables and whatnot, you can change to a few ohms to dampen things). The CP2102 only runs at full speed (12MHz) so it's fairly forgiving in this regard.

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your answer. But my question is: There is any advantage about connecting VDD to my LDO output? Or I can use VBus to supply the CP2102? What's the better approach? I understand your point about left VRegin disconnected if I'm not using the regulator, but in datasheet they never left this pin disconneted. Do your really think there is no problem?

Comment: The datasheet for the CP2102 shows in Fig.9 on page 21 that Vregin should not be left disconnected, but should be connected to the 3V power net when the internal regulator is not being used.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Fixed. Seems a little weird but I trust the datasheet.